# Trying to write a an Excel macro to find a large text string and copy to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with a column of cells that each contain several paragraphs of text. I'm trying to write a macro that will grab several sentences between these text phrases "How we made our decision" and "Conclusion"

The location of this text string varies from sheet to sheet but the column is always consistent.

I've been able to find a bunch of vba scripts that allow me to find and copy 1 word at a time or simple batches of single word. I'm just not able to figure our or find something that allows me to copy an entire paragraph from within a single cell of paragraphs.

The code below just grabs the entire table. As you can see in the beginning portion I was able to get what I need however I found out that the (70) is irrelevant because the table size changes with each pull of the record.

```
Sub GetTheData()
Dim T As String
 Dim SWs As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
 Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
 Dim LetPr As InternetExplorer
 Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
'Dim IE As Object
 Dim tbls, tbl, trs, tr, tds, td, r, c

 For Each IE In SWs

    If IE.LocationName = "Letter Preparation Case Summary – Member Case"       Then
        Set LetPr = IE

        'LetPr.document.getElementById
        T = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(70).innerText
        'T = Trim(Mid(T, InStr(T, "How We Made Our Decision: ") + 0, InStr(T, "Conclusion") - (InStr(T, "How We Made Our Decision:") + 26)))

          Exit For
    End If

Next
Set tbls = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")
For r = 0 To tbls.Length - 1
    Debug.Print r, tbls(r).Rows.Length
Next r

Set tbl = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(9)
Set trs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")

For r = 0 To trs.Length - 1
    Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("td")
    'if no <td> then look for <th>
    If tds.Length = 0 Then Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("th")

    For c = 0 To tds.Length - 1

        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(r, c).Value = tds(c).innerText
    Next c
Next r

 End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please clarify - does the phrase "How we made our decision" appear multiple times in the same Cell? Multiple times in the same sheet? Is each sheet a new block of paragraphs which has only a single "how we made our decision", or does each sheet contain many blocks of paragraphs?

Comment: Also - please show the VBA code you are working on now if you want a VBA solution.

Comment: a) re: *'varies from sheet to sheet'* Did you want to collect them all? Where were you going to put them? b) re: *'but the column is always consistent'* What column? c) re: *'a bunch of vba scripts that allow me to find'* I cannot see any such code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that you wanted the text *'between these text phrases'* so the beginning position of the found text will have to be adjusted by hte length of the searched string.

```
dim beginStr as string, endStr as string, beginPos as long, endPos as long

beginStr = "How We Made Our Decision:"
endStr = "Conclusion"

beginPos = instr(1, T, beginStr, vbtextcompare)
endPos = instr(beginPos, T, endStr, vbtextcompare)

if cbool(beginPos) and cbool(endPos) then
    beginPos = beginPos + len(beginStr)
    T = Trim(Mid(T, beginPos, endPos - beginPos))
end if
```

That last `endPos - beginPos` might have to be adjusted by subtracting 1.